# Attempted to load class "AssetsHelper" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper"

Tags: symfony

[image]

Attempted to load class "AssetsHelper" from namespace "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper"

Comment: The first politeness is to write and ask question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your question is why you got this error message? The answer is that this is an outstanding issue in Symfony 3.0 (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17041).

EDIT: The patch has been merged in the meantime and will be part of the next Symfony 3.0 patch release.